# How do I cache results in my nginx server

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I have the following nginx.conf file that is supposed to be a reverse proxy (inside a docker container) for redirecting requests from `...:80/content/api/v1/<more>` and redirect it to `HTTP://$host:3000/<more>` where each request from the client should be cached for 10 minutes.

I have tried many different configs but nothing works. This is the most recent one. The requests get successfully redirected but none of the results are getting cached. I am new at Nginx.

```
events {

}

http {
    limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=request_rate:10m rate=5r/s;
    proxy_cache_path /var/cache/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=my_cache:10m max_size=10g inactive=10m use_temp_path=off;

    server {
        listen 80;

        location ~ ^/content/api/v1/(.*)$ {
            limit_req zone=request_rate burst=10 nodelay;
            proxy_pass http://$host:3000/$1;
            # proxy_set_header Host http://$remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host http://$host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_buffering on;
            proxy_cache my_cache;
            proxy_cache_valid 200 10m;
            proxy_cache_methods GET HEAD POST;
            proxy_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri"
        }
    }
}
```

Even after making requests to the same URL a few times, the server listening on port:`3000` recalculates each response. If the proxy loads the response from cache, the response shouldn't even reach the server?

The response time for the requests stay around ~350ms for ~3.5KB json responses